# Avoid Tabs from disappearing when searching

Tags: android

i've got a tabbed layout, and on one of the tabs i have a search functionality. When the user makes a new search, i need to show the results. However, doing so involves starting another `activity` to handle the search results.

this causes the tabs at the bottom to disappear. The user can get the tabs back by clicking on the '`back`' button. But somehow, in the context of my application this can be a bit counter-intuitive and seems to be break the common layout flow.

is there any way to prevent the tabs from disappearing when invoking the search from one of the tabs?

thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can understand your problem, You are not using tabs then you are using buttons. see some tabhost tutorials on how to create a tabbed activity. what you are doing is launching a new activity instead of just switching a tab in the existing one.

Also the other things you can look for are activity groups.

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, and having consulted the android developer tutorials - i am fairly confident that i am using 'tabs'. The way my tabs are structured is that there's one class which extends `TabActivity` and the different tabs are `Activity` sub-classes which are added to the `TabHost` of the main `TabActivity` class. In one of the tab `Activity` class, i'm trying to implement a search functionality using the search dialog method.